# Why does a legitimate cors request that works on Chrome fail on FireFox?

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

I'm trying to process a csv file obtained from a server that is different from the one serving the script:

```
fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/webflo/countries/master/countries.csv").then(response=>{
    console.log(response.body)
})
```

This works on Chrome, `response.body` is a `ReadableStream` from which I can read the content.

However on FireFox the `response` does not have a `body`, so it is `undefined`.

What is the reason for this and how can I modify the script so that it works on FireFox as well?

Comment: I removed unnecessary code, now it is self contained.

Comment: You need to give *exact* versions. "Firefox" and "Chrome" have had dozens of major releases with thousands of point releases.

Comment: [Firefox doesn’t support `body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/body#Browser_Compatibility) (yet). Nothing to do with CORS. Do you actually need a stream, or would you be okay with the content as a single string?

Comment: @JaredSmith: literally just paste it into current firefox

Comment: @Ryan The stream was intended to be able to process large csv files on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using native `fetch` and `response.text()` the following works fine for me in Firefox

```js
fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/webflo/countries/master/countries.csv")
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Data length =', data.length)
    let arr = data.split('\n').map(line => line.replace(/\"/g, '').split(','));
    console.log(arr);
  })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works.both on Chrome and FireFox. Stream was intended for large csv files, but this particular file is relatively small.